# Error [RunScriptError]: Run "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c electron-builder install-app-deps" error, exit code 1

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, electron, electron-builder

question:
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/29273

The installation package keeps failing and reporting errors, please give some suggestions I will be very grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reply from issue, thank you very much the developer
[image]